# Android Google Map sometimes not working

Tags: android, google-maps

I have two Activities both using com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView. The API key is properly set up. One Activity is working fine, the other is showing grey screen and

> ... W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates not found.
>
> ... I/DynamiteModule: Considering local module com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates:3
>
> ... I/DynamiteModule: Selected remote version of com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates, version >= 3
>
> ... W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/user_de/0/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/00000000/n/x86

Anyone knows what may be going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Found the reason. This happens if you write to fast and forget to forward life cycle events from `onCreate`, `onResume`, `onPause`, `onLowMemory`, `onSaveInstanceState`, `onDestroy` to the map.